# Javascript else if statement on click counter variable does not change

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the number hits my if statements it changes to the right value.
But if I click again, the value goes back to what it was before.
My question is.
How do I change my main variable to continue from where I am in my if statements? eg variable = 1 if it hits 2 jumps to 10 and continues 11,12,13 etc. Thanks in advance to everyone who takes the time to help me, I really appreciate it :)

```js
function updated(val) {
  var ValuUpDown = 10101;
  ValuUpDown += val
  if (ValuUpDown === 10001) {
    ValuUpDown = 420401
  }
  if (ValuUpDown === 10401) {
    ValuUpDown = 10601
  }
  if (ValuUpDown === 10501) {
    ValuUpDown = 10301
  }
  console.log(ValuUpDown)
};

var counter = 0;
$("#nesteHøyre").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  counter += 100;
  updated(counter);
});
$("#nesteVenstre").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  counter -= 100;
  updated(counter);
});
```

Comment: Declare `var ValuUpDown = 10101;` globally outside the function? Because as it stands, you are assigning  the value everytime the function is called

Comment: ^ as above. You reset valuUpDown to 10101 every time you call updated().

Comment: Because you declare valUpDown inside the updated() function, it will be initialized back to 10101 every time the function is called. Declare the valUpDown variable outside the updated() function and it might help with your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your helpfull notes :) 
Thanks to you i figured it out.

What i am making is an app for our wearhouse and the locations they are placed at has no consistant placing.
So the numbers need a lot of if statements for it to work.
so i need it to go from location 010101 to location 420202.
and they all end at different locations depending on the length of the shelfs.

se the final soulution below :) 
BTW. 
Im not done with all the if statements yet.

```
function updated(val){

console.log(counter)

}
var counter = 10101; 

$("#nesteHøyre").click(function (e) { 
e.preventDefault();
counter += 100;
if(counter === 10401){
  counter = 10601
}if (counter === 12001){
  counter = 20101
}if (counter === 21601) {
  counter = 30101
}if (counter === 31601) {
  counter = 40101
}if (counter === 41601) {
  counter = 50101
}if (counter === 51601) {
  counter = 60101
}if (counter === 61501) {
  counter = 70101
}if (counter === 71501) {
  counter = 80101
}if (counter === 81201) {
  counter = 90101
}if (counter === 90601) {
  counter = 200101
}if (counter === 200301) {
  counter = 210101
}if (counter === 210301) {
  counter = 220101
}
//console.log(counter)
updated(counter);
});
$("#nesteVenstre").click(function (e) { 
e.preventDefault();
counter -= 100;
if(counter === 10501){
  counter = 10301
}if(counter === 20001){
  counter = 11901
}if (counter === 30001){
  counter = 21501
}if (counter === 40001){
  counter = 31501
}if (counter === 50001){
  counter = 41501
}if (counter === 60001){
  counter = 51501
}if (counter === 70001){
  counter = 61501
}if (counter === 79901){
  counter = 71401
}if (counter === 90001){
  counter = 81201
}if (counter === 200001){
  counter = 90501
}if (counter === 210001) {
  counter = 200201
}if (counter === 220001) {
  counter = 210201
}
//console.log(counter)
updated(counter);
});
```